# IE8 OpenWindow does not work when downloading a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have a simple script  which opens an new window using javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.open("/test/test.aspx", "", "", "");
</script>
```

This works great when dealing with normal webpages, but when I try to download pdf file using :

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
context.Response.WriteFile(fileFullName);
```

I can see the window opening but it closes directly afterwards. This behavior is only shown when not working in local, when accessing a different server.

When using different browser thant IE8, there are no problem, the download works perfectly.

I have for the moment find a work around opening a page with a link in it, so that the user click and access his download, but I do not like the solution so much.

thanks for your inputs,

[EDIT]
Here is a simplified code  :

page1 :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.open("/page2.aspx", "", "", "");

    </script>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

page 2

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string fileFullName = ApplicationStoringPath.TempReportPath + "00329bad-28ac-46bd-9f0a-3eced660f079.pdf";
            string fileName = "test.pdf" ;

            if (File.Exists(fileFullName))
            {
                FileStream file = File.Open(fileFullName, FileMode.Open);
                long length = file.Length;
                file.Dispose();


                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename=\"{0}\"", fileName));
                Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
                Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
                Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

                Response.WriteFile(fileFullName);
            }
        }
```

Here what happens :

Accessing page 1 from local opens popup and proposes the download. (IE)
Accessing page 2 from local proposes the download.(IE)

Accessing page 1 from different PC opens popup and does not propose the download. (IE)
Accessing page 2 from different PC proposes the download. (IE)

Accessing page 1 from different PC opens popup and proposes the download. (FireFox)
Accessing page 2 from different PC proposes the download. (FireFox)

This is not some popup blocker situation. The file that I try to access is located in the temp folder of the site that host my pages, ie the same server.

[EDIT]

Comment: What are you actually doing in test.aspx? Are you writing directly to Response? Can we see the code?

Comment: You might be running into a XSS prevention measure in IE.  Any chance you can test it with a PDF that's stored on the same server as the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi all thanks for your help.

Whatever I tried using a popup did not succeed and therefore I tried using an iframe to make my download. Luckily it worked like a charm.

same code then but I now use :

```
<iframe id="DownloadIFrame" visible=false height=1 width=1></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">


    document.getElementById('DownloadIFrame').src = "/page2.aspx";

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case file was downloading but open-save pop-up was not showing. I just enabled 'Automatic prompting for file download' and it worked :)

Open Internet Explorer > Tools > Internet Options > Security > Custom level > Download :
Select Enable for 'Automatic prompting for file download'.

Comment: This worked for us. We were opening the new window and downloading a MS Word document into it. It has been working fine for years but either an upgrade to Win7 or IE8 along the way caused it to stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be you have a Popup blocker on IE8 that is not configured yet?